# How to make this kind of global hotkey?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create global shortcut to run command line applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24063/create-global-shortcut-to-run-command-line-applications)

I want to assign a command to a certain key. This command will fire no matter what window is active. It will do the same thing as typing a certain command in terminal. I was able to do this in Linux, but how can I set this up in OSX Lion?

I want to run the terminal command without the terminal window opening up at all.

Comment: By command, do you mean a Unix-style command-line command?Do you want this command to run in a new Terminal window, in the frontmost existing Terminal window, or to run but not in a window at all? It looks like your question is the same as the one identified above as a duplicate, but if you are asking something else, edit to show the differences and we can reopen this.