# Keyboard, notification, or menubar shortcut to compose mail message?

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, macos, notifications

Im looking for a quick way to bring up a compose mail message dialogue.

Either a keyboard shortcut, or even a little tool within mountain lion's new notification center would be cool.

Anyone got anything?

Comment: Could I suggest some external software?

Comment: @qegal go for it

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way out-of-the box is to use the "services menu". Just select some text anywhere (a single character will do), right click to open the context menu and select the bottom-most item "Email Selection":

[image: Screenshot of Email Selection]

If it is not present (should be) you need to enable it under System settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard commands -> Services -> Text

Answer (score 1):

[Mail Unread Menu](http://loganrockmore.com/mailunreadmenu/) is what you want. Free/donation-ware. Compose New Mail from the menubar.

Also custom alerts and more. Working well in Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to [assign a shortcut to an AppleScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28272/3936) like this:

```
tell application "Mail"
    make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true}
    activate
end tell
```