# How to quickly send new mail without opening mail application?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, quicksilver

I know Quicksilver has a plug in for quickly sending new mail messages without opening the Mail application.

But the Quicksilver plug in doesn't work under Mountain Lion.

How do you send a new mail message from Mail using Mountain Lion similar to the Quicksilver approach using preferably free application?

Comment: It's not really an answer, but [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) is compatible with Mountain Lion and has a quick mail shortcut. It isn't an answer since it does pass the message to the Mail app (if running) or launches Mail app to do the sending.

Comment: Actually it still a good answer, actually that what I was aiming for, however LaunchBar costs money, and I'm looking for a free application.

Comment: I thought LaunchBar is free for limited use - if all you do is Mail, you won't run into the ten item limit. Also look into [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) which is paid / but with a free tier for low usage. That combined with `/usr/bin/mail -s subject` and some light AppleScript or Automator would let you roll a keyboard initiated mail sender for free and with as much UI as you please.

Comment: A new mail plugin for Quicksilver is currently under review and will be released shortly. So in a few days, you'll be able to send mails with Quicksilver just like you used to.

Comment: Great, I really like QS, good news :-)

Comment: A related question: [Keyboard, notification, or menubar shortcut to compose mail message?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58631/keyboard-notification-or-menubar-shortcut-to-compose-mail-message/58661#58661).

Answer (score 3):

Check out QuickMailer. It's similar to LaunchBar but I feel that it's easier to use. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

If you're a keyboard-junkie like me, it has shortcuts to compose mail and send mail (Compose: Ctrl + ⌥ + ⌘ + m, Send: ⇧ + ⌘ + d) to speed up the mailing process too!

It isn't free, but it's pretty cheap at 99 cents. I don't own it so I haven't tried it out, but I've heard great things about it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Are you sure you meant Quicksilver? It's free and I'm already using it, but don't see this feature.

Comment: @Anonymous - Sorry. It's actually QuickMailer

Answer (score 2):

The Email Support plugin for Quicksilver was updated on 8/17/12 which enables you, once again, to quickly send new email messages. See the [qsapp site](http://qsapp.com/plugins.php) for more but the updates include:

- works with Quicksilver in 64-bit mode
- full documentation provided
- visible notifications are shown when sending a message fails
- Compose E-mail action now uses your selected client instead of the system default
- icons for actions match the application that will perform those actions
- improved preferences
- direct sending updated to use MailCore (should support authentication, SSL, etc.)
- enhancements to the QSMailMediator protocol

After some experimenting I've been able to send messages through mail.app easily, but still trying to configure to send in the background and use other mail clients. I'm sure we'll see an article on the Love Quicksilver blog soon...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the very underestimated Services Menu. Just mark any text, a single letter is sufficient, and control-click to open the context menu. At the bottom you will find the item "Send selection by mail" or "New mail with selection" or something similar.

If you don't see it, open system settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> services -> text (or similar, my Mac talks German with me) and enable "send selection by mail". If you don't find "send selection by mail" just add it using the Automator.

Once setup (usually no setup is required, since it is enabled by default) is completed, this is the fastest way to get a New Mail window.

[image: This is the context menu for a selected text]