# Minimize other windows of an application

Tags: macos, window-manager

Is it possible to do the equivalent of "Hide other Applications" for Windows of the same application?

Say i have around 4 main windows open for Chrome and each has 10 tabs. I would like to switch to Window 3 of Chrome and hide the other Chrome windows (Window 1, 2 & 4). Essentially i want to hit a CMD+M on the other "windows".

(*this is different from Minimize/Hide other Applications that would allow me to switch to Safari and hide other applications like Chrome*).

A keyboard shortcut would be awesome, but cursory googling tells me that i'll have to settle with an applescript?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work with Preview or other aplications that don't support AppleScript.

```
tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
    try
        set miniaturized of windows where visible is true and index is not 1 and miniaturizable is true to true
    end try
    try -- at least Finder
        set collapsed of windows where visible is true and index is not 1 and closeable is true to true
    end try
end tell
```

I don't know how to get the focused window or hidden windows with System Events. The focused window isn't window 1 or AXMain or AXFocused. Setting AXMinimized to true didn't work with Tweetbot either.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where frontmost is true)
    windows where value of attribute "AXMinimized" is false
    --repeat with w in result
    --try
    --set value of attribute "AXMinimized" of w to true
    --end try
    --end repeat
end tell
```

There are many ways to [assign shortcuts to scripts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24063/create-global-shortcut-to-run-command-line-applications/28272#28272), but shortcuts for Automator services don't work reliably in 10.7 or 10.8.