# Is it possible to create shortcuts for VLC using Automator?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator, vlc

I see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40887/61618) that Automator can be used to create commands that then can be triggered globally.

I have no idea how to use Automator but see that it has some options for involving applications... Can a "service" be created for VLC that will then be bound to keystroke triggers?

What I want are simple commands like pause/play, back and forward that could be used with shortcuts no matter what other window application is on top.

Comment: Just out of interest what Mac do you have.

Comment: @Buscar웃 - macbook air and mavericks

Comment: My MBA has the media keys for that function, do they not work for you?

Comment: @Buscar웃 - there are three on my keyboard, next, previous and play/pause. i am interested in a larger range of shortcuts that would work in the same way, especially in back/forward (within the same file). vlc has three levels of jump back-forward, iTunes only one. I use this for transcription so it is a big difference to me

Comment: If you press the back-forward keys, it's go back/forward in the same file...

Answer (score 2):

You can create services like this:

[image]

Then give the services shortcuts from System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services.

I prefer using [third party applications](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) instead of services to assign shortcuts to scripts though. There has been a bug since 10.7 where the shortcuts for services don't always work until you hover over the services menu from the menu bar (or for example run a service once from the menu bar). There is also a noticeable delay before services are run, and the shortcuts for services don't work when an application that doesn't have a services menu (like Tower) is frontmost.

More examples:

```
tell application "VLC"
    if playing then
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "VLC"
            click menu item "Pause" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Playback" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    else
        play
    end if
end tell
```

```
tell application "VLC"
    set n to 60
    if duration of current item - current time > n then
        set current time to current time + n
    else
        next
    end if
end tell
```

```
tell application "VLC"
    set fullscreen mode to not fullscreen mode
end tell
```

```
tell application "VLC"
    volumeUp
end tell
```

Open VLC's dictionary in AppleScript Editor to see all supported terminology.