# Run command from terminal by shortcut

Tags: terminal, keyboard, command-line, bash

I am trying to run `copyq menu` which is opening the menu context. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24063/create-global-shortcut-to-run-command-line-applications) supposed to worked, but I got `copyq command not found` and struck at this step.
I had tried putting the `/Users/myname/.bash_profile` but it does not work.
I also had tried `do shell script "copyq menu"` command not found either

The ultimate goal I wants is I am be able to use shortcut to call `copyq menu`

`OSX: 10.13.4
CopyQ Clipboard Manager v3.4.0 (hluk@email.cz)
Built with: Qt 5.10.1`

**Question**
How to get `copyq menu` runs by shortcut?

Answer (score 3):

I have to set up the `Show the tray menu` Since in my fresh install from `brew` is blank https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/issues/938

Set the short cut `main window` here

[image: Show/hide main window]

`main window` with a few items

[image: picture of main window]

Set the short cut `tray menu`
[image: Show the tray menu]

`tray menu`

[image: tray menu]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install CopyQ on your Mac - e.g. through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

`brew cask install copyq`

The full description can be found here: https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/ - and how to use it.