# How to make path prompt easier to read by color-coding each `/` (forward slash)?

Tags: terminal, iterm, path, zsh

I would like to get another configuration for the path, more a detail than a real request:

Below an example of zsh `PROMPT` :

[image: prompt zsh]

**In order to make reading the path easier, I would like to change dynamically the color, except for the first slash (into `~/`) of every slash in the path in blue (more precisely `%F{75}`) by the color pink (`%F{13}`)** But I would like to be able to use with deeper path, that would help me to better locate myself into the tree.

On the image above, this would be only one pink slash changed (**Phd_2019_2020`/`Travail_3_...**).

Here's my current `PROMPT`:

```
PROMPT='%F{13}|%F{green}%n@%F{cyan}%m%F{13}|%f%T%F{13}|%F{75}%~%F{13}|%F{7} '
```

**Is it possible to perform this dynamic change of color with zsh-5.8 ?**

Comment: Please don't change the question once you start getting answers. If problems with an answer come up, use comments *beneath* the answer; if new questions come up, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: @nohillside You are rude, you have removed all my **UPDATE1**, please restore it temporaly at least, avoiding me to all rewrite for another question.

Comment: It‘s still in the edit history, just click on the blue text on top of my name above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to have your prompt display the *entire* path of your current directory in blue but with each of the forward slashes ("/") in pink.

**Unfortunately, you can't do this in your prompt.**

### Use the builtin `precmd ()` function.

ZSH gives us a `precmd` function which is similar to Bash's `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  These allow a command to be issued before the prompt is displayed.

I also wouldn't recommend a long prompt anyway as it makes usability very difficult when entering commands. Putting the full directory *above* your prompt is much better from a UI standpoint.  The following code accomplishes that.

Simply put the following in your [`~/.zprofile`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/388622/119271).

```
precmd ()  { printf "\n"; pwd | awk -F "/" ' {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "\033[01;34m"$i"\033[38;5;206m/"; printf"\n" }' }
```

And here are the results:

[image: iTerm Window with precmd results]

The above screenshot is my iTerm window showing that I have traversed deep into my `/Applications/Firefox.app` directory with the current directory formatted in blue separated by pink forward slashes.

---

### How it Works...

I've expanded the one line `premcmd` function above so that it's multi-line and added in some variables so we can better see what's going on.

```
precmd() {
printf "\n";
pwd | awk -F "/" '{ blue="\033[01;34m"; \
                    pink="\033[38;5;206m"; \
                    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) \
                      printf blue $i pink "/"; \
                      printf "\n"
                   }'
}
```

Here's what it all means:

- `printf "\n"` prints out a new line char.  This is for aesthetics.
- `pwd` returns the working directory name ([`man pwd`](https://ss64.com/osx/pwd.html)) which is then [piped](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) ("|") to the next command, `awk` ([`man awk`](https://ss64.com/osx/awk.html)).
- `-F "/"` defines the field separator to the forward slash; `awk`'s default is a space.  I kept my prompt to it's short and succinct setup.

Within the awk "program," delimited by the braces ("{" and "}") we have the following:

- variables `blue` and `pink` are set to their [ANSI escape codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33206814/4703819) `\033[01;34m` and `\033[38;5;206m` respectively.
- We then have a for/do loop that iterates through each of the fields that `awk` has processed.  `NF` is the total number of fields.
- `printf blue $i` and `printf pink "/"` prints out the directory name in blue and the forward slash in pink

---

Comment: thanks a lot ! Just a last thing, how to make the correspondance between the classical blue/pink colors and the colors that I would like to use, i.e %F{75} and %F{13} and mostly, how to declare them since the following function doesn't work : `slash_color ()  { pwd | awk -F "/" ' {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%F{75}$i%F{13}/"; printf"\n"     }' }` with the following PROMPT :  `PROMPT='%F{13}|%F{green}%n@%F{cyan}%m%F{13}|%f%T%F{13}|$(slash_color)%F{13}|%F{7} '` (using `setopt PROMPT_SUBST` before) ?

Comment: look up the ANSI color codes I linked.  "Classic" blue/pink isn't a reliable descriptor.  The "blue" I selected came from the 4-bit color codes, so it's probably closest to your "classic" blue.  Pink was in the 8-bit and 256-bit color sequences.

Comment: Also, you can't put a function in your `PROMPT` if that's what you're trying to do.  My answer explains how to get what you want and that's to use `precmd()`

Comment: From this post https://superuser.com/questions/142099/get-function-into-ps1-zsh, I can use a function inside zsh prompt as long as I declare before `setopt PROMPT_SUBST`

Comment: @youpilat13 - I'll have to take a look at that.  ZSH has a TON of features that need to get enabled, but from my security side of my brain...I don't like the idea of a prompt calling a function..Example, I could write a wrapper that checks for `sudo` being issued and then issue a nefarious command to download and install malware with admin privileges.  That said...there also a TON of useful stuff there as well.

Comment: @Allan slight modification: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388754/zsh-issue-with-colorized-prompt-and-double-slash-i-e-appearing-when-i-am-i?noredirect=1&lq=1