# ZSH issue with colorized prompt and double slash, i.e "//" appearing when I am into root

Tags: terminal, iterm, color, path, zsh

I am faced to a problem of `appearing slash / appearing double slash` into `PS1` when I am located on root `/` .

I explain more precisely, I have in `.zshrc` :

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
slash_color () { dirs | awk -F "/" ' {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {printf "\033[38;5;75m"$i"\033[38;5;206m" "/"}} '; }
PS1='%F{13}|%F{green}%n@%F{cyan}%m%F{13}|%f%T%F{13}|$(slash_color)%F{13}|%F{7} '
```

The goal was to colorize each slash of the current PATH.

This way, when I go to a deeper directory, I get :

[image: prompt colorized with slash]

But a problem remains when I do : `$ cd /`, I get the following result, i.e a double slash representing the  current path and I don't know to handle this to have only a single path :

[image: double slash issue]

If someone could help me to get only one slash when I am located on root, i.e `/` ?

Comment: though an interesting case occurs if you have a filename/ folder name with a slash in between

Comment: @ankii Did you try to create such a file?

Comment: @ankii Slash != Backslash. Try `touch foo/bar` :-)

Comment: @nohillside https://i.stack.imgur.com/al3tW.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRRxi.png though I did that in finder. Idk about terminal

Comment: @ankii If you look with Terminal you'll find the `/` replaced by `:`, so it won't be an issue for the problem here. Finder is doing some legacy HFS magic on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [How to make path prompt easier to read by color-coding each `/` (forward slash)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388696/how-to-make-path-prompt-easier-to-read-by-color-coding-each-forward-slash/388720#388720)

Change the for loop from

```
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) \
 printf blue $i pink "/"; \
printf "\n"
```

to

```
for (i=1; i<NF; i++) \
 printf blue $i pink "/"; \
printf blue $NF pink; \
printf "\n"
```

- notice the change in `<=` → `<`
- Take care of semi-colons.

or use some help from searching to get an if else condition for which the pseudocode (not correct bash syntax) is:

```
for all i<=NF:
 if (i<NF):
   printf blue $i pink "/" ;
 else:
   printf blue $i pink ;
printf "\n";
```

Comment: @ankli thanks a lot ! I am faced now to another issue but this is another story too, so new question, to follow ...