# How can I get .zshrc to run in its entirety every time I open zsh

Tags: command-line, iterm, zsh

Here is the entirety of my `.zshrc`.

```
alias ll='ls -l'
export HOME='/Users/rcorty/Dropbox'
```

This file is at `/Users/myname/.zshrc`.

When I start iTerm2, I check whether the home directory was reset by entering `ls ~` and I recognize the files in my Dropbox -- success!  Then I enter `ll` and I am met with `zsh: command not found: ll`.

Weird.  Then I run `source /Users/myname/.zshrc`.  Now I do the same two checks and they both succeed (HOME is Dropbox and `ll` is `ls -l`.

I'm rather novice with shells in general and zsh in particular.  From my reading of the zsh [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html), it seems like .zshrc should essentially be "sourced" each time I start a shell.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Here's one of the things that break when you change your HOME environment variable.  ZSH is looking for `.zshrc` in `$HOME`.

Comment: I thought about this...but since I have the alias before the change in HOME...it should still work?  Or should I put only the change in HOME in myname/.zshrc and make another .zshrc in Dropbox?

Comment: See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388623/119271

Comment: @Allan, thank you for sharing that link -- I had a look through the page and nothing jumped out at me as super relevant to this question.  Were you providing background information?  Or is there something in particular you wanted to draw attention to?

Comment: background info and the fact that a system wide files get loaded and sets environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it's working now.  `/Users/myname/.zshrc` is:

```
export HOME='/Users/rcorty/Dropbox'
```

and `/Users/myname/Dropbox/.zshrc` is:

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```