# I placed Neovim in usr/local/bin but getting permission denied

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, permission, vi

I'm not sure where to place the Neovim folder (after extracting it). Is the location usr/local/bin correct?

I get the following

zsh: permission denied: nvim

Comment: What exactly did you download and from where? Was it a pre-built binary or did you compile it yourself from source code?

Comment: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases

Comment: Make sure you place it in `/usr/local/bin` and not some ambiguous `usr/local/bin`

Comment: Could it be https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/11011#issue-493430261 unverified developer

Answer (score 2):

The location of an executable is much less important for it to be run from Terminal than its permissions.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types/

Check them by running

```
ls -la /usr/local/bin/nvim
```

> I'm not sure where to place the Neovim folder

You can place it anywhere you want as long as the shell can find it. Shell finds items using a variable named `PATH`.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#Unix_and_Unix-like
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh

> Is the location [/]usr/local/bin correct?

It is correct only if this location is in `PATH`. Check it by running `echo $PATH` in your terminal. I personally like `~/Applications`. If it is not in `PATH`: Open `~/.bash_profile`/ `~/.zshenv` in your text editor and add the following line to it

```
 PATH="/usr/local/bin":"$PATH"
```

- [ZSH: .zprofile, .zshrc, .zlogin - What goes where?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388622/zsh-zprofile-zshrc-zlogin-what-goes-where/388623#388623)

> zsh: permission denied: nvim

You have two choices here:

- Use Homebrew to install it and no longer worry about putting files in `lib` or `share` or `bin` folder.
- Run

  ```
  chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/nvim
  ```