# Homebrew PATH set in .zshenv is overridden

Tags: homebrew, path, zsh

Following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71258/361424) about best practices for configuring Zsh, I wanted to move my Homebrew `PATH` initialization to the `~/.zshenv` file:

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

This modifies `$PATH` by placing the Homebrew directories first, so that tools installed with Homebrew take priority over system tools:

```
PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

However, after the shell starts up, the Homebrew directories are *last*:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:...:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After `~/.zshenv` is sourced, the next file that is loaded is `/etc/zprofile`, which is provided by macOS. This script executes

```
eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
```

The manual for `path_helper` explains:

> The path_helper utility reads the contents of the files in the directories `/etc/paths.d` and `/etc/manpaths.d` and appends their contents to the `PATH` and `MANPATH` environment variables respectively.
>
> ...
>
> Prior to reading these directories, default `PATH` and `MANPATH` values are obtained from the files `/etc/paths` and `/etc/manpaths` respectively.

In my opinion it is unclear from the description, but `path_helper` appears to rebuild `PATH` in the following order:

1. Directories listed in the file `/etc/paths`
2. Directories listed in the files in `/etc/paths.d` (note: files are not enumerated in sorted order)
3. Any other directories that were previously in the `PATH` variable, excluding those that appear in the above lists

Therefore, `path_helper` ends up moving Homebrew to the end of `PATH`.

The solution is to do path initialization in `~/.zprofile` on macOS. This file is loaded after `/etc/zprofile` and before `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Basically Apple couldn't read the zsh documentation and put path_helper in the wrong place

Comment: Thank you for this, I discovered the same after putting many debug echo statements in every single /etc/z* and ~/.z* file like `echo '/etc/zprofile sourced.'` and discovered that macOS does things differently. Bummer.