# What happened to the .zshrc

Tags: macbook-pro, zsh

I am trying to setup my new MacBookPro M2-Max.

I can't find the .zshrc, the only hidden files in my home folder are:

```
.zprofile
.zsh_history
.zsh_sessions
```

But no .zshrc

My OS is Ventura. Any ideas?

Comment: It’s not created by default.  You don’t really need it as `.zprofile` can handle things. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/388622/119271 for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, `~/.zshrc` is not created by default in macOS. However, you can create it easily enough:

```shell
% touch ~/.zshrc
```

There's a [nice Q&A here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388622/zsh-zprofile-zshrc-zlogin-what-goes-where) that summarizes *one opinion* of the [raison d'être](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=raison+d%27etre&atb=v278-1&ia=definition) for the `~/.zshrc` file. And there's [another opinion here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout), which also suggests what types of configuration parameters should go into a `~/.zshrc` file. You didn't ask what to put in `~/.zshrc`, and I assumed the two references covered that in enough detail... but one of the comments suggested I should say something explicit.

Clearly, Apple has deemed `.zshrc` *unnecessary*, but many people use it. I keep (among other things) my HISTORY configuration there.