# Automator run shell script does not know my PATH?

Tags: terminal, automator, environment-variables

When I use the "run shell script" in automator, and do, for example

```
say $PATH
```

it then tells me the PATH. But the path is incomplete. Some items I have in $PATH when using the terminal (zsh) are missing.

How can I fix this, so I have the same $PATH variable everywhere?

Comment: You can't - running from Finder/desktop does not read your zsh startup files. See many questions here. You have to explicitly source them in your script you run from automator

Comment: @mmmmmm But it does have part of my PATH, so it must be possible to add my paths somewhere to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different shells - interactive and non-interactive.  They behave just like they are described - interactively and non-interactively.

If you set your path in .zprofile, for example, anything you do in Terminal will have the path you set.  However, a non-interactive shell (like when run from Automator) won’t read .zprofile so any variables like PATH won’t be set.  I suggest using .zshenv or setting the path manually in your shell script.

See [ZSH: .zprofile, .zshrc, .zlogin - What goes where?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/388622/119271) for a full description of what should go where when setting paths.

Answer (score 1):

Automator's shell script action does not configure additional paths (such as  `/usr/local/bin`) into the script's environment variable. To get these additional paths configured, make a call to the `path_helper` utility.

The following is an example snipped for a `bash` script to configure additional paths into the scripts' environment. Insert this near the top of your shell script action.

```bash
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As Allan said, the shell environment variables, such as $PATH, are typically set in the shell configuration files (e.g., ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc). However, when you use Automator's "run shell script" action, it does not necessarily load your shell configuration files, which may result in a different $PATH variable than what you have in your terminal.

To ensure that you have the same $PATH variable in Automator's "run shell script" action as in your terminal, you can explicitly set the $PATH variable in your script. You can do this by adding the following line at the beginning of your shell script:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/your/additional/path/here"
```

This command sets the $PATH variable to the existing value of $PATH (represented by "$PATH") plus any additional directories you want to add (separated by colons).

Alternatively, you can source your shell configuration file at the beginning of the script by adding the following line:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

This command sources your ~/.zshrc file, which will set the $PATH variable to its proper value.

By doing either of these, you can ensure that your "run shell script" action in Automator has the same $PATH variable as your terminal.